# Is there a word for "false accuser"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I robbed you which makes you angry and then I blame you for being angry even though I caused it. So in a sense I'm accusing you falsely and making you a scapegoat. Is there a single word for what I should be called if I make false accusations in that specific way that I caused the situation even putting the blame on you ("scapegoat")?

Comment: An allegator, which is obsolete, by the way. But I kind of like it. Sounds like....

Comment: @Lambie I'd like to include that the allegator did it himself. Similar to a thief who is pretending to be the victim or similar.

Comment: I don't get the "accusing you falsely" part.  You can be genuinely mad at your friend for being mad at you, regardless for the reason.  I'd say that it's more irrational than a case of false accusation.  Or maybe you're feeling guilty about making him mad at you in which case you'd be guiltily turning the tables on him.

Comment: Well, the Brits say he's a wanker. :)

Comment: @Lambie Not to mean that. *Wanker* and *tosser* have the same very specific meaning and the same non-specific ones. Neither meaning is complimentary, but nor do they in any way imply false allegation.

Comment: *Traducer* seems to come close, especially after a peek into the OED.  It may not be spot-on to what you're seeking, though.

Comment: @Lambie You might say the allegator is crying crocodile tears :) .

Comment: I get the gist of what you're asking, but please clarify. What are you accusing your friend who is angry *of*? What you blaming them *for*? Is the friend accusing you of stealing and you're pretending to be outraged? Or do they not have a suspect? If they are blaming you, I would not say you are making them a scapegoat. Rather, you are shifting the focus off of yourself using *false indignation* or *false outrage* at being blamed.

Comment: Sounds like the guy who murdered his parents and asks the judge to excuse him because he is an orphan.

Comment: Also sounds like a specific behavior pattern of a *sociopath*

Comment: Not in the dictionaries, but you could say that person is a *blame-shifter*

Comment: Sounds like Julian Assange

Answer (score 2):

The term *victim blaming*, or *blaming the victim* has entered into common usage as seen in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_blaming).

If you needed a noun or noun phrase, you could say *victim blamer*.

Answer (score 0):

**defamer**
 de·fame  (dĭ-fām′)

1. To damage the reputation, character, or good name of (someone) by
   slander or libel.
2. (Archaic) To disgrace.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/defamer